# How to call angular controller function when ons-switch is changed?

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm just getting into angular and onsen-ui and ran into a simple problem.  I'm hoping the answer is trivial.

I have a ons-switch which I want to execute code in my controller when the switch is changed:

```
<ons-switch var="mark_as_favorite" onchange="toggleFavorite()"/>
```

This results in a toggleFavorite is not defined.  This makes sense, because the scope is probably different.  So how do I access the controller method from the ons-switch?

--Keith

Comment: I think I have a solution.  I used the $emit directive on the ons-switch and listened for the event in the controller:   <ons-switch var="mark_as_favorite" ng-click="$emit('toggle')"/>

Answer (score 1):

If you are unfamiliar with AngularJS, use var attribute. var attribute dispose a Onsen UI element as a global variable.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        ons.bootstrap();

        function checkIsSwitchEnabled() {

            // mySwitch is disposed as a global variable. So mySwitch is accessible from everywhere.
            var isChecked = mySwitch.isChecked();

            alert(isChecked);
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator" page="page1.html">
    </ons-navigator> 
  </body>
</html>
```

**page1.html**

```
<ons-page>
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>    
    <ons-switch var='mySwitch' onchange='checkIsSwitchEnabled()'></ons-switch>        
  </div>
</ons-page>
```

Comment: Thanks Ataru.  The one thing I was trying to do is call the Controller directly from the ons-switch tag.  So, when the user touches the control I can act on it immediately.  Another option would be to bind the ons-switch tag to the model.  I'm thinking what I'm trying to do is not possible.

Comment: It seems that the binding to ons-switch tag by using onchange doesn't work for now. Though, you can handle the change of ons-switch tag by adopting ngClick and $scope.$watch, sorry I think my answer is not trivial.

Comment: Hi Atura,  thanks for the feedback.  Using the event broadcast seems to be working for now.  I'll have to read up on $watch.

Answer (score 1):

this is what i did..

**html**

```
<ons-page ng-controller="yourcntrl">
 <ons-switch modifier="list-item" ng-model="obj.IsSelected" ng-change="switchTrigger(obj)"></ons-switch>
</ons-page>
```

**Js**

```
myApp.controller('yourcntrl', function ($scope) {
 ons.ready(function () {
     $scope.switchTrigger= function (obj) {
        alert(obj.IsSelected);
     }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `ngModel` directive, Onsen will apply that model to the underlying checkbox and your variable will be updated automatically on change

```
<ons-switch ng-model="mark_as_favorite">
```

This is especially useful if you need to update other things on the page as they will update automatically. I use this to show and hide additional options based on the checkbox value and to apply conditional classes:

```
<div class="example" ng-class="{favorite: mark_as_favorite==true}">Some content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ng-change` attribute to execute code when the ons-switch is toggled.
Example:

```
<ons-page ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ons-switch ng-model="MyCtrl.switchState" ng-change="MyCtrl.toggleSwitch(event)">/ons-switch>
</ons-page>
```

Now you can use `event.value` to access the boolean if the switch is on or off.